# Error in wide to long format in r reshape2 package

Tags: r, format, reshape2

Hi I am new in R programming.

I want to change a list of data from wide to long format but the error comes out as follows:

```
EA    UU    AR
0.455 1.106 0.568
1.406 0.710 0.262
1.124 1.406 0.312
```

change to:

```
EA 0.455
EA 1.406
EA 1.124
UU 1.106
UU 0.710
UU 1.406
AR 0.568
AR 0.262
AR 0.312
```

The code used by me is as follows:

```
files <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "*.txt", all.files = TRUE, full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE)

listy <- lapply(files, read.csv)

melt(listy)

write.table(melt(listy), file = "listofdata.txt", quote = FALSE, sep = " ", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

The errors that come out are:

```
No id variables; using all as measure variables

No id variables; using all as measure variables

No id variables; using all as measure variables

No id variables; using all as measure variables

No id variables; using all as measure variables

No id variables; using all as measure variables
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are using a `list` of `data.frames` do the `melt` within each `list` element.

```
 listN <- lapply(listy, function(x) melt(x))
```

It is not clear whether the OP wanted to write the output in a single file or multiple files.

If it is a single file, `rbind`, the `list` of `data.frames` to a single one and then use `write.csv`

```
 dfN <- do.call(rbind, listN)
 write.csv(dfN, "dataLong.csv", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

But, if this goes as separate files, then loop through the `names` of the 'dfN' and write it

```
 lapply(names(listN), function(nm) write.csv(listN[[nm]], 
                 paste0(nm, ".csv", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

Comment: thanks, but can i ask listN <- lapply(listy, function(x) melt(x)), function(x) and melt(x), that x stands for in this case is? x = listy ?

Comment: @PeterChung  The `x` stands for each element of `listy` as we are looping through the list elements.

Comment: sorry for my clumsy , i don't get it. so what is the function inside the lapply () . I have a list of data from separated files and wanted to gather in R and changed them from wide to long format and output as a single file.

Comment: @PeterChung If you want as a single file, use the first code.  The function call is anonymous call.  Basically, what it does is that loop through the column names, subset the `listN` (`listN[[nm]]`) based on its name, and then write that as a separate file (file name generated with `paste`